# Correct use of Java 8 supplier consumer

Tags: java, stream, consumer, supplier

I'm still strugling with Suppliers and Consumers for Java 8, I have this:

```
final Set<String> roles = new HashSet<>();
user.getRoleGroups().forEach(rg -> rg.getRoles().forEach(r -> roles.add(r.getName())));
```

To get a Set from role names that are inside a list of Roles inside a list of RoleGroups.
Pretty sure I could use something in one line with .stream().map() and RoleGroup::getRoles and Role::getName to get this Set. But I don't know how.

Comment: See if this works: `final Set<String> roles = user.getRoleGroups().stream().flatMap(rg -> rg.getRoles()).map(r -> r.getName()).collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close! To use a `Stream` instead, do something like this:

```java
final Set<String> roles = user.getRoleGroups().stream()
   .flatMap(g -> g.getRoles().stream())
   .map(Role::getName)
   .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Use of `flatMap()` is the only tricky part here. The `flatMap()` operation transforms an element to a `Stream`, which is concatenated with the `Streams` from the other elements.

Comment: quite likely this wouldn't work with `flatMap(RoleGroup::getRoles)` and you would need `flatMap(rg -> rg.geteRoles().stream())`